# CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL fails (Toll-Free bridging of NSURL to CFURLRef)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, pdf, core-graphics

I've got the following function:

```
- (void)loadPdfFromPath:(NSString*)path
{   
    NSURL *pathUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:path];

    _pdfDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pathUrl);
}
```

Which from the documentation I'm lead to believe will work because you can case from an `NSURL*` to a `CFURLRef` via [Toll-Free Bridging](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Toll-FreeBridgin/Toll-FreeBridgin.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH2). However, this function fails, and I get the following output in the log:

> CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource: error code -15.

NB: -15 = `kCFURLImproperArgumentsError`

However, if I create an actual `CFURLRef`, it works absolutely fine:

```
- (void)loadPdfFromPath:(NSString*)path
{
    CGPDFDocumentRelease(_pdfDocument);

    CFStringRef cgPath = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, [path UTF8String], kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

    CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(NULL, cgPath, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, 0);

    _pdfDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(url);

    CFRelease(url);
    CFRelease(cgPath)
}
```

What am I missing? I'm happy to keep the second function in my code, but I'd rather know why the first one is failing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert a file system path to a URL, use

```
NSURL *pathUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
```

`URLWithString` expects a RFC 2396 conforming URL string like "http://..." or "file:///...", including the "scheme" etc.

***Added:*** Actually `NSURL *pathUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:path];` returns a valid object, so it *seems to work*, but reading from this URL (e.g. `dataWithContentsOfURL`) fails.

Comment: +1. It won't always even seem to work if `path` has characters that are invalid in a URL, such as spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You need the convert NSString to CFStringRef then call  CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath;

```
CFStringRef aCFString = (__bridge CFStringRef)path;
CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath (NULL, aCFString,  kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, 0);
NSLog(@"NSURL %@",url);
```