# Crash whille Converting NSURL to CFURL

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl, cgcontextref

I want to create pdf in document directory and want to give page numbers so I need CGPDFDocumentRef object.

```
let fileName: NSString = "test.pdf"

let path:NSArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)

let documentDirectory: AnyObject = path.objectAtIndex(0)

let pdfPathWithFileName = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName as String)

UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfPathWithFileName as String, CGRectZero, nil)

let ref : CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

let localUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(pdfPathWithFileName)
```

I have converted file path in url but this below line generates a crash and I don't know why..?

```
let pdfDocumentRef: CGPDFDocumentRef = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(localUrl as CFURLRef)!
```

Comment: Do you have any output from the crash? Also, try extracting the `localUrl as CFURLRef` to a separate line and see if that is `nil` by any chance, I'm guessing that this is where you problem lies.

Comment: @pbodsk : Yes it returns nil and I don't know why..? this line returns CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(localUrl as CFURLRef)! nil. Although localUrl has a file path.

Comment: In Swift, you don't need to explicitly name the type that a variable is if Swift can infer the type.  For instance, `let path:NSArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)` can easily be represented as `let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)`, with the added bonus of Swift knowing the types used by the array is a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Its because your `test.pdf` is not present into document directory folder.

Comment: No I have tested already. Test.pdf is gets created every time when I run app.

Answer (score 0):

```
 let localUrl  = pdfPathWithFileName as CFStringRef
 let pdfDocumentRef = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(nil, localUrl, CFURLPathStyle.CFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false)
 let page_count = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdfDocumentRef)
```

Comment: It does not crash w/ your code but pdfDocumentRef returns nil.

Comment: Now it should work, if NSURL fail to convert , just try to convert the previous string..

Answer (score 0):

So it seems your `NSURL(fileURLWithPath: pdfPathWithFileName) as CFURLRef` part fails and that is what is causing your problems.

I just found this in the [documentation about CFURL](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFURLRef/)

> CFURL fails to create an object if the string passed is not well-formed (that is, if it does not comply with RFC 2396). Examples of cases that will not succeed are strings containing space characters and high-bit characters. If a function fails to create a CFURL object, it returns NULL, which you must be prepared to handle. If you create CFURL objects using file system paths, you should use the CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation and CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentationRelativeToBase functions, which handle the subtle differences between URL paths and file system paths.

And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15849081/cgpdfdocumentcreatewithurl-fails-toll-free-bridging-of-nsurl-to-cfurlref) seems to be about the same problem. As [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36781439/4063602) suggest:

> You need the convert NSString to CFStringRef then call CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath;

Hope that helps you.

Comment: As you can see in my code I have already used fileUrlWithPath.

Comment: and what is the value of `localUrl` then?

Comment: file:///Users/anil.kukadeja/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AC107F46-79C0-49B6-9773-0BB0672E8902/data/Containers/Data/Application/7BE0B88F-45A0-45BB-B01F-A41F18D7A2FF/Documents/test.pdf

Comment: Sorry...I have no more ideas :(